# how to to get values from other table and merge in separate table in blade template in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I want to merge the value from another table. For this, I am using a relationship.

Here's my View Template:

```
  <td><a href="" class="pglst-lnk">{{$value->business()->where('business_name')->get()}}/{{$value->page_url}} </a></td>
```

Here, I am getting `page_url` value perfectly and I want to merge the value of the `business_name` with this. As you can see, I have a `business()` method.

Here's the `business()` method in my Model.

```
 public function business()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Business','business_id');
 }
```

The output of `page_url` is `shahzad123` and that is correct. But the `business_name` outputs `[]` an empty array. So the final output becomes `[]/shahzad123` which is incorrect because business_name is empty.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hey shahzad. you are doing it the wrong way you can't query like that in your blade template

Comment: [passing data to views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views) just read this you will get better idea

Comment: please add your table structure and controller code in your question

Comment: what result do you expect? and why you do query in your view? not in your controller?